# InterlliJ: CommonJS exports default object properties not accessible via dot notation

Tags: javascript, object, babeljs, es6-modules, commonjs

Given following content of an import...

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports["default"] = void 0;
var _default = {
  SOME_CONSTANT: 'Some constant text'
};
exports["default"] = _default;
```

...transpiled from an original ES6 export via babel...

```
export default {
  SOME_CONSTANT: 'Some constant text'
}
```

...why would my IDE (PHPStorm / IntelliJ) report the following (dot notation) as `unresolved variable`...?

```
import textConstants from 'package-name/path/to/textConstants'

console.log(textConstants.SOME_CONSTANT)
```

If I convert it to (bracket notation)...

```
console.log(textConstants["SOME_CONSTANT"])
```

...inspections get satisfied, no warning is showing.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like adding...

```
{ "modules": false }
```

...to my .babelrc file as an option to the `"@babel/preset-env"` preset does the trick.

So the content of my .babelrc file is...

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": false }]
  ]
}
```

...while my dev dependencies in package.json file are...

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6"
  }
}
```